# How to solve this taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(); in new method of firebase storage

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-storage

As taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() is depperacted so I followed the firebase post as to get the URL

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg");
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

 Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new        Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
@Override
public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        throw task.getException();
    }

    // Continue with the task to get the download URL
    return ref.getDownloadUrl();
}
   }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
    } else {
        // Handle failures
        // ...
    }
}
});
```

but I want

```
 String downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

instead of

```
 Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
```

How I can do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches I came to know the answer by changing:

```
String downloadUrii = downloadUri.toString();
```

will be the solution